# javascript variable assigning to asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This my script to get the latitude,longitude and place name. i can get only latitude longitude but not the place name.

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var longitude = $('#longitude');
            var latitude = $('#latitude');
            var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                    longitude.text(p.coords.longitude);
                    latitude.text(p.coords.latitude);
                    document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = p.coords.latitude + "," + p.coords.longitude;
                    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
                    //   alert(p.coords.latitude);
                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: LatLng,
                        zoom: 20,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: LatLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude,

                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                    var hidPlace = '<%= inpPlace.ClientID %>';
                     var lblplace = $('#lblplace');
                    var google_maps_geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    google_maps_geocoder.geocode(
                        { 'latLng': LatLng },
                        function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0]) {
                                lblplace.text(results[0].formatted_address);
                            }
                        }
                    );

                });
            } else {
                alert('Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```html
 <section class="content">
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=key"></script>
        <label id="latitude" runat="server"></label>
        <br />
        <label id="longitude" runat="server"></label>
        <br />
        <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px" runat="server" visible="false"></div>
        <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <input id="locHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
         <label id="lblplace" runat="server"></label>
         <input id="inpPlace" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <br />

    </section>
```

asp.net c# code behind i can get the inphide as latitude and longitude, but the lblplace is returning null value every time. please support me to find where i am doing the wrong.

with the hidden field

```html
           var hidPlace = '<%= inpPlace.ClientID %>';
                     var lblplace ='<%= locHide.ClientID %>'
                    var google_maps_geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    google_maps_geocoder.geocode(
                        { 'latLng': LatLng },
                        function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0]) {
                                document.getElementById(hidPlace).value=results[0].formatted_address;
                            }
                        }
                    );
```

Comment: The place name should be set to the corresponding hidden field instead of the label; `document.getElementById(hidPlace).value = ...`

Comment: You cannot use a `<Label>` to send text from browser to server. You need some `<input>` instead.

Comment: `<label id="lblplace" runat="server"></label>` Have you checked the id of this label by inspecting the webpage? I think you need to set `<label id="lblplace" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"></label>`

Comment: @pfx i tried with hidden field not return the value. same time input and i tried with clientidmode also.

Comment: Please update the question to see how it looks when using the hidden field. I assume that the `geocode` callback gets executed and contains a value(?)

Comment: Updated please check.i am not getting any data on server side, null/empty value.

Comment: Then check the content of `results`.

Comment: there is data, if i put the alert i can see the result(formatted_address)

Comment: `<label id="lblplace" runat="server"></label>` have you tried inspecting the page html using developer tools to confirm the id of the generated html label? Also, what happens if you try `alert(lblplace)`? Here lblplace is jquery element reference to your label

Comment: @MohsinMehmood the value/text of a label does not get included in postback data, meaning it never reaches serverside code.

Comment: Check whether this hidden field is still addressable from wihin the callback; eg. `alert(document.getElementById(hidPlace).length)`

Comment: @pfx thanks for your input. Looking at the code posted in question I think the requirement is just to show the place name pulled from google geocode api response in a label. If there is a requirement to access the place name on server-side code then definitely hidden field is needed.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood only i can see the value in inpHide, other variable are null.

Comment: <input name="ctl00$cphMain$locHide" type="hidden" id="cphMain_locHide">

Comment: Are you putting alert statement for printing `formatted_address`  inside this if clause
                            `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0]) {`

Comment: Can you try my last suggestion? Also inspect the page afterwards to see which values were being set.

Comment: function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0]) {
                                alert(results[0].formatted_address);
                                document.getElementById(hidPlace).value = results[0].formatted_address;
                                lblplace.value(results[0].formatted_address);
                            }

Comment: @pfx i dont know how i can do that, please help me.

Comment: Set the alert as in my comment within the `if (status == ...)` block.

Comment: i did already that. it returns the result.

Comment: Please notice that my alert does not output the address but a number about whether the hidden field is addressable.

Comment: no alert for that.

Comment: Then please check the developer tools of your webbrowser, as it should alert 1 if the hidden field gets found, otherwise 0.

Comment: if copy this script to separate project i can access the place name in the label. but not here